# trouble updating my database using jsp,servlets,java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Hi i have trouble updating my elements inside my database. It seems that the values I have in my columns from the database wont appear. I need it that so that I can update my database but this is what I get [this is the what it displays in my jsp page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAA8q.png)
    {

This is my Servlet

```
empServices empserv= new empServices();

if (request.getParameter("process") !=null && request.getParameter("process").equals("updemps")) 

    {


empgs.addAll(empserv.updAll(request.getParameter("serialS")));
            request.setAttribute("empdetails", empgs);
            RequestDispatcher updrd = request.getRequestDispatcher("updDetails.jsp");
            updrd.forward(request, response);


    }

else if (request.getParameter("process") != null && request.getParameter("process").equals("edit"))
        {
            //some process here

        }
```

Here is my DAO where this part would bring the contents from the database to the jsp page hopefully

```
public ArrayList<empGetSet> getupdemp()
{

    ArrayList<empGetSet> empdtls = new ArrayList<empGetSet>();

    try {

        Connection conn = getConnection();
        String updsql = "UPDATE csemp SET Fname=?,Lname=?,NameResource=?,JRSS=?,Band=?,Acct=?,PMPSeat=?,SeatJRSS=?,OpenSeatDesc=?,ReqSkills=?,ReqBand=?,DReject=?,RReject=?,DetActionPlan=?,DataCompletion=?,Status=? WHERE SerialNumber=?";
        PreparedStatement psupd= conn.prepareStatement(updsql);
        ResultSet rsupd = psupd.executeQuery();

        while (rsupd.next()) 
        {

            empGetSet readgetset = new empGetSet();

            readgetset.setfName(rsupd.getString(1));
            readgetset.setlName(rsupd.getString(2));
            readgetset.setNameRes(rsupd.getString(3));
            readgetset.setSerialS(rsupd.getString(4));
            readgetset.setjRss(rsupd.getString(5));
            readgetset.setBanD(rsupd.getString(6));
            readgetset.setAccT(rsupd.getString(7));
            readgetset.setpMPS(rsupd.getString(8));
            readgetset.setSjRss(rsupd.getString(9));
            readgetset.setOpenSeatDesc(rsupd.getString(10));
            readgetset.setReqSkills(rsupd.getString(11));
            readgetset.setReqBand(rsupd.getString(12));
            readgetset.setdReject(rsupd.getString(13));
            readgetset.setrReject(rsupd.getString(14));
            readgetset.setDetActPlan(rsupd.getString(15));
            readgetset.setDataComplete(rsupd.getString(16));
            readgetset.setStaT(rsupd.getString(17));


            empdtls.add(readgetset);

        }
        psupd.close();
        conn.close();

    }


    catch (Exception e)
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return empdtls;

}
```

And this is my other method at DAO to edit the contents of the DB

```
public void updEmp (String fName, String lName, String nameRes, String serialS, String jRss, String banD, String accT, String pMPS, String sjRss, String openSeatDesc, String reqSkills, String reqBand, String dReject, String rReject, String detActionPlan, String dataComplete, String staT) 
{
    try {

        Connection conn = getConnection();
        String updsql = "UPDATE csemp SET Fname=?,Lname=?,NameResource=?,JRSS=?,Band=?,Acct=?,PMPSeat=?,SeatJRSS=?,OpenSeatDesc=?,ReqSkills=?,ReqBand=?,DReject=?,RReject=?,DetActionPlan=?,DataCompletion=?,Status=? WHERE SerialNumber=?";
        PreparedStatement psupd = conn.prepareStatement(updsql);

        psupd.setString(1, fName);
        psupd.setString(2, lName);
        psupd.setString(3, nameRes);
        psupd.setString(4, serialS);
        psupd.setString(5, jRss);
        psupd.setString(6, banD);
        psupd.setString(7, accT);
        psupd.setString(8, pMPS);
        psupd.setString(9, sjRss);
        psupd.setString(10, openSeatDesc);
        psupd.setString(11, reqSkills);
        psupd.setString(12, reqBand);
        psupd.setString(13, dReject);
        psupd.setString(14, rReject);
        psupd.setString(15, detActionPlan);
        psupd.setString(16, dataComplete);
        psupd.setString(17, staT);

        psupd.executeUpdate();


            System.out.println("Details Updated!");


        psupd.close();
        conn.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Here is my jsp page

```
<title>Update Details</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="right"><a href="loggedin.jsp"><button>Back</button></a></div>

<form action = "empServlet" method ="get">
<c:forEach items ="${empdetails}" var="empdet">

First name:
  <input type="text" name="eFname"  value ="${empdet.fName}" required /> 
  <br>
  <br>
Last name:
  <input type="text" name="eLname" value ="${empdet.lName}" required/>
  <br>
  <br>
Name of Resource (LN ID Format):
  <input type="text" name="eNameRes"  value="${empdet.nameRes}" required/>
  <br>
  <br>
Serial Number:
  <input type="text" name="eSerials"  value ="${empdet.serialS}" required/>
  <br>
  <br>
JRSS:
  <input type="text" name="eJrss" value ="${empdet.jRss}" required/>
  <br>
  <br>
Band:
  <input type="text" name="eBand"  value ="${empdet.banD}" required />
  <br>
  <br>
Account(Proposed):
  <input type="text" name="eAcct" value ="${empdet.accT}" required/>">
  <br>
  <br>
PMP Seat:
  <input type="text" name="ePMPs" value ="${empdet.pMPS}" required/>
  <br>
  <br>
Seat JRSS:
  <input type="text" name="esJRSS"  value ="${empdet.sjRss}" required/>
  <br>
  <br>
Open Seat Description:
  <br>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name ="eOpenSeatDesc" placeholder = "Enter descriptions here" required>${empdet.openSeatDesc}</textarea>
  <br>
   <br>
Required Skills:
  <input type="text" name="eReqSkills" value ="${empdet.reqSkills}" required/>
  <br>
  <br>
Requested Band (low/high):
  <input type="text" name="eReqBand" value ="${empdet.reqBand}" required/>
  <br>
  <br>
Date of Rejection:
  <input type="text" name="eDreject" value ="${empdet.dReject}" required/>
  <br>
  <br>
Reason for Rejection:
  <br>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder = "Enter reasons here" name= "eRreject" required>${empdet.rReject}</textarea>
  <br>
   <br>
Detailed Action Plan:
  <br>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder = "Enter details here" name= "eDetActPlan" required>${empdet.detActPlan}</textarea>
  <br>
  <br>
Target Date of Completion:
  <input type="text" name="eDataComplete"  value ="${empdet.dataComplete}" required/>
  <br>
  <br>
Status (Ongoing,Closed):
  <input type="text" name="eStat"  value ="${empdet.staT}" required/>
  <br><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" >

</c:forEach>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE UPDATE~~~
* I have finally displayed the contents :) (im so happy) can I ask another question friends? how can I truly update this. I mean when I click the submit button at the update jsp, it would store the new values to the DB. btw thanks guys!

Comment: What is the issue update sql query or JSP output ?

Comment: the jsp output, it wont show the details inside the db, so that i can edit it, instead it shows "c:out value ="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems like you failed to import JSTL core tag in your JSP. Also make sure to get the jar file. Add the below line on the top of your JSP.

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
```

Also make sure that EL(Expression Language) is enabled for JSP. How to test if EL is disabled/ignored? Try a simple expression and see if it yields a result(enabled) or prints as it is(ignored). e.g. `${3 + 4}` must print the result `7`.

Last one, to print you don't really need do use `<c:out value="${empdet.fName}"/>` just use `${empdet.fName}` still will give you same results, so try this instead without having to import JSTL, `<input value="${empdet.fName}" type="text"/>`. But make sure that `empdet` is set in scope(page/request/session/application).

Comment: ive included that bro, btw thanks, i have eliminated the <c:out value= by using what you've said, but still I cant display the contents of the database to the edit page

Comment: I've updated my code men thanks and added another question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
<c:out value='${status.value}' />
```

instead of

```
<c:out value ="${empdet.fName}"/>
```

and same for others.

---

Clarification about spring bind and status variable...

status is a variable used by spring bind. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/taglib/tag/BindTag.html

Also you need to bind your field values with spring bind.

Change this

```
First name:
  <input type="text" name="eFname" required value ="<c:out value ="${empdet.fName}"/>">
  <br>
  <br>
```

to

```
<spring:bind path="empdet.fName">
        First Name: <input 
            type="text"
            value="<c:out value="${status.value}"/>"
            name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>">
            <c:if test="${status.error}">
                Error codes:
               <c:forEach items="${status.errorMessages}" var="error">
                    <c:out value="${error}"/>
                </c:forEach>
            </c:if>
    </spring:bind>
```

etc.

Comment: thansk bro, but what do you mean status.value??

Answer (score 0):

1. ResultSet is for select query.
2. If you are running update .Use executeUpdate() or execute.
3. If there is list use c:for

   String query = "Query";
         PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
         preparedStmt.setInt   (1, 6000);
         preparedStmt.setString(2, "Fred");

   ```
     // execute the java preparedstatement
     preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
   ```

Comment: when i turned it to: String updsql = "UPDATE csemp SET Fname=?,Lname=?,NameResource=?,JRSS=?,Band=?,Acct=?,PMPSeat=?,SeatJRSS=?,OpenSeatDesc=?,ReqSkills=?,ReqBand=?,DReject=?,RReject=?,DetActionPlan=?,DataCompletion=?,Status=? WHERE SerialNumber=?";
   PreparedStatement psupd= conn.prepareStatement(updsql);
  
   psupd.setString(1, fName); ---- fName gives me an error

Comment: can you please specify exception that came